# How to get most frequent values in SQL where value like a variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL table, in which I store my application logs. I have a column errors, in which I store values like this example

```
+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|  id  |  name  |  error                                       |
+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+  
|  1   |  john  |  Flushing folder error on folderid 456       |
|  2   |  paul  |  Flushing folder error on folderid 440       |
|  3   |  gary  |  Error connection has timed out on source 320|
|  4   |  ade   |  Error connection has timed out on source 220|
|  5   |  fred  |  Error connection has timed out on source 821|
|  6   |  bob   |  Reading errors occured on folder 400        |
|  7   |  ade   |  Error connection has timed out on source 320|
|  8   |  fred  |  Error connection has timed out on source 320|
|  9   |  bob   |  Reading errors occured on folder 402        |
|  10  |  ade   |  Error connection has timed out on source 320|
|  11  |  fred  |  Error connection has timed out on source 320|
|  12  |  bob   |  Reading errors occured on folder 400        |
|  13  |  paul  |  Flushing folder error on folderid 100       |
+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
```

The result I would like to get is something like :

```
+-------------------------------------------+------------+
|  Error Like                               |  Occurence |
+-------------------------------------------+------------+ 
| Error connection has timed out on source  | 7          |
| Flushing folder error on folderid         | 3          |
|Reading errors occured on folder           | 3          |
+-------------------------------------------+------------+
```

Is there anyway I could do that in SQL? Errors are variables and I don't have the exhaustive list of all possible errors.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the last digit part and count.

**Query**

```
SELECT LEFT(error, LEN(error) - 4) AS [Error Like], 
COUNT(LEFT(error, LEN(error) - 4)) AS [Occurence]
FROM tbl_error
GROUP BY LEFT(error, LEN(error) - 4);
```

Or you can do it with a sub-query also.

**Query**

```
SELECT t.[Error Like], COUNT(t.[Error Like]) AS [Occurence] FROM(
    SELECT LEFT(error, LEN(error) - 4) AS [Error Like]
    FROM tbl_error
)t
GROUP BY t.[Error Like];
```

***If you are not aware about the last digit part, then***

**Query**

```
SELECT t.[Error Like], COUNT(t.[Error Like]) as [Occurence] FROM(
    SELECT LEFT(error, LEN(error) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(error), 1)) AS [Error Like]
    FROM tbl_error
)t
GROUP BY t.[Error Like]
ORDER BY COUNT(t.[Error Like]) desc, t.[Error Like];
```

**Result**

```
+--------------------------------------------+-----------+
| Error Like                                 | Occurence | 
+--------------------------------------------+-----------+
| Error connection has timed out on source   | 7         | 
| Flushing folder error on folderid          | 3         | 
| Reading errors occured on folder           | 3         | 
+--------------------------------------------+-----------+
```

[**Find a demo here**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/483956/error-like-occurence)

Comment: This solves the problem partially. I might have some errors like " Error on xxxx folders". The digit part here is not the last 4 characters of the error message.

Comment: @RafaAyadi: It is difficult to give you an adequate answer, if you don't give a precise description of the problem.

Comment: Then you might use `CHARINDEX` with `REVERSE`

Comment: @RafaAyadi: Your examples show only error numbers at the end and all of them have 3 digits. It is not clear whether this is always the case and it is not clear whether the varying part is always a number.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to strip out the last four characters and aggregate:

```
select left(error, len(error) - 4) as ErrorLike, count(*)
from applogs
group by left(error, len(error) - 4)
order by count(*) desc;
```

Comment: This solves the problem partially. I might have some errors like " Error on xxxx folders". The digit part here is not the last 4 characters of the error message

Comment: @RafaAyadi, then adjust your samle data!

Comment: @jarlh I'm not the one who generates error messages. These are error messages generated as a response from Google/Office365 APIs. I don't have any hand on this.

Comment: @RafaAyadi . . . Perhaps not.  But you *can* control the error messages you put in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

The below query will work with out hard-coding the error id size. Let assume your table name is `LogDetails`

```
SELECT E.[ErrorDetail], COUNT(E.[ErrorDetail]) [ErrorCount], 
FROM (
    SELECT REPLACE(error, Substring(error, PatIndex('%[0-9]%', error), LEN(error)), '') [ErrorDetail]
    FROM LogDetails
    WHERE error LIKE '%[0-9]%'
) E
GROUP BY E.[ErrorDetail]
ORDER BY COUNT(E.[ErrorDetail]) DESC
```